# How to make alternative name for UILabel's text attribute?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, pointers, uilabel

Probably a real newb question. I've got a `UILabel` called `routeOutLabel`. I want to make it easy to access its `text` attribute.

I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
@synthesize routeOutText = &routeOutLabel.text;
```

but it doesn't work. How can I get `routeOutText` to point to `routeOutLabel.text`, so to change the second, I only have to set the first?

Comment: It sounds like you have a JAVA background. Using Objective-C it is considered common practice to access the properties directly as, e.g. self.routeOutLabel.text = @"Awesome Text";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why? A `UILabel` has other properties too. There is no reason to do what you are asking. It will make your code harder to read and maintain.

But having said that, you could define a private property like this in the .m file:

```
@interface WhateverClassThisIs ()

@property (nonatomic) NSString *labelText;

@end

@implementation WhateverClassThisIs

- (void)setLabelText:(NSString *)text {
    self.routeOutLabel.text = text;
}

- (NSString *)labelText {
    return self.routeOutLabel.text;
}

@end
```

Now in your code you do this:

```
self.labelText = @"Hello";
```

instead of:

```
self.routeOutLabel.text = @"Hello";
```

If outside classes need this shortcut, move the property declaration to the .h file.